# Why the author takes $\forall c \in C$ and not $\forall b \in B$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

In the following picture:

[image]

The answer of 2(b), the direction ($\Rightarrow$), when I proved it by myself I said "$ \forall b \in B$" because I know that $f$ is an R-module homomorphism, but the author said $\forall c \in C$ and I do not understand why, could anyone explain this for me please?

[image]

Comment: Also, when you say "I proved it myself", shouldn't you show your reasoning as part of the question? That way, if you made an error, it could be pinpointed.

Comment: @quasi yes I used the surjectivity of $f$ by starting with $b \in B$.

Comment: @quasi my prove is exactly the same as what is written in the picture except that I took "For any $b \in B$" because the codomain of $f$ is B and not C as given in the problem statement, why the author take $C$?

Comment: Ok, yes, I see. You're right, but it's clearly just a typo, nothing more. The outputs from $f$ are in $B$, not $C$, and the inputs to the functions $k,t$ are in $B$, not $C$. Maybe there's an errata page for the text? Which text, by the way?

Comment: But in your question you indicate that your proof is for the ($\Leftarrow$) direction, however the author's proof, as shown in your question, is for the ($\Rightarrow$) direction.

Comment: it is a file that I downloaded  from the internet but I do not know how to upload it for you here, if you know please tell me how?@quasi

Comment: There's no way to upload a document. But if you have the link the document, you can post that. Do you have the link?

Comment: @quasi sorry it is a mistake, I will correct the arrow.

Comment: What is the title of the document, and who is the author?

Comment: I tried to search for it another time on the internet but could not find it ..... it has no name for the author ..... give me your email and I can send it for you.@quasi

Comment: That's OK, no need to send it. In any case, the issue is resolved. Good catch! (+1).